# celery create more worker and hangs the task

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

With Celery 5.1.2 in python 3.11, when using the command "celery -A project -l info -c 5", celery creates more than 7 workers, and celery hangs the task after accepting it.The environment is Django + redis5.0.14.1 + celery5.1.2 in windows.I used command "celery -A worker -l info -P eventlet". it is working, but i want to know why the first was wrong.And i can use the first command in python3.6,celery can work normally.
this is celery instance code

```
#celery_app.py
import os
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING', '1')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_celery_test.settings')
django.setup()

celery_app = Celery('django_celery_test')
celery_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

this is setting code

```
setting.py
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json']

CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60 * 60 * 24

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True

CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'django_celery_test.celery_task'
)


CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),
)
```

I want to start celery normally and execute tasks in python 3.11 or at least python 3.7

Comment: I used command "celery -A worker -l info -P eventlet". it is working, but i want to know why the first was wrong

Comment: Please edit this comment into your question, ideally at the top, that's a really important piece of information.